# ModuleNotFoundError when calling package script, but not when source module file is directly executed

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am new to Python, and I am practising with [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). This is the structure of my project:

```
.
├── README.md
├── package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
    └── __init__.py
```

and here are the files:

`module1.py`

```py
""" module1 module. """


class Module1():
    def func1(self):
        print("module1.func1")
```

`module2.py`

```py
""" module2 module. """
from module1 import Module1

class Module2(Module1):
    def func1(self):
        print("module2.func1")
```

`__main__.py`

```py
""" __main__ module """
from module1 import Module1
from module2 import Module2


def main():
    print("main!")
    module1 = Module1()
    module1.func1()
    module2 = Module2()
    module2.func1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Moreover, in file `pyproject.toml` I have the following section:

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
package1 = "package1.__main__:__main__"
```

After having called `poetry shell` (it actually just activates the virtual environment):

- If I execute `python package1/__main__.py`, it works as expected:

```
main!
module1.func1
module2.func1
```

- If I execute `poetry build`, then `pip install .` and finally `package1` I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/repos/package1/.venv/bin/package1", line 5, in <module>
    from package1.__main__ import __main__
  File "/home/user/repos/package1/package1/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from module1 import Module1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
```

What is the correct way to import my modules in main file, in order to make it work in both cases? I already tried

```py
from .module1 import Module1
from .module2 import Module2
```

and

```py
from package1.module1 import Module1
from package1.module2 import Module2
```

but no luck.

Comment: I recommend to always use absolute imports. And absolute imports must always start with a top-level importable package (or module). So in your case, the imports should start with `package1`. -- Instead of `python package1/__main__.py` you have to call `python -m package1`.

Comment: It also depends on which directory you run the script.

Comment: Can you describe why do you need `pip` if you are using poetry?

Comment: @Rustam-Z because if I just execute `poetry build`, the executable named `package1` will be not present in `.venv/bin`, hence it can't be executed. If I install the package locally with `pip install .`, executable will be there

Comment: You can also use `poetry install`, this will install the project as "editable".

Comment: @sinoroc thx! it's true: no need of `pip install .` if `poetry install` is used